# jQuery with Meteor.js [Template.name.rendered]

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, meteor

i've read that when you have Template.name.rendered = function(){ ... }
You can use regular jQuery code in it.

I am trying to make it possible to when a user post a comment, the post either slides down or pops up depending on what i put in the jQuery code..

Here is what i have so far

```js
Template.posts.rendered = function(){
    if (!this.rendered){
     
  function setEvents(){
 
    $(".posts").on("click", function(){
      $(this).slideDown(750);
    });
};
 
var init = function(){
                setEvents();
        }();
    this.rendered = true;
  }
};
```

Comment: You gotta create new event like `'click .posts': function(event){ $(event.currentTarget).slideDown(750)}`

Comment: do i put this inside the renderer template?

Comment: No, inside events of template https://www.meteor.com/try/4

Comment: Should the jQuery code apply to the user creating the post, or to all users viewing the post?

Comment: it to all users veiwing posts, so after a user have posted the post upon click.. i want it to slideDown or fadeIn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Meteoric way of doing this is using Template *events*

```
Template.posts.events({
  'click': function(){
    $(".posts").slideDown(750);
  }
});
```

Comment: i already have a template events:

Template.groupPage.events({
  
  "click #post": function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var post = $('textArea').val();
    
    var groupName = this.groupName;
    if(post.length > 0){
        Meteor.call("addPostToGroup",  post, groupName);
        $('textArea').val('');
        $('.posts').slideDown(750);
    }
  }
});

Comment: You can have multiple template events. In your example you have "click #post" but you can also have "click .post" or clicks on specific UI elements.